# How do I find the sum of series 1+ (1*2) + (1*2*3) … (1*2*3*…n) using recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

So this is what I have so far,

```
def factorial(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1 
  else: 
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

to calculate the factorial, but how do I add the sums?

Comment: The simple recursion relation is: sum_fun(n) = sum_fun(n-1) + factorial(n)

Comment: You're almost right. Please check my answer, I have corrected it. To make sure, the above one is correct, you can also check the below factorial_expression() function which forms the expression (string) using recursion.

Answer (score 5):

@DarryIG and @bkbb's answers would work but are inefficient since it makes repeated recursive calls with the same numbers, which have the same results, over and over again for the higher numbers. You can cache the results for better efficiency.

Also, since:

```
sum_factorials(n) = (sum_factorials(n-1) - sum_factorials(n-2)) * n + sum_factorials(n-1)
```

you don't actually need two functions to implement the recursion:

```
def sum_factorials(n, cache=[0, 1]):
    if len(cache) > n:
        return cache[n]
    previous = sum_factorials(n - 1)
    cache.append((previous - sum_factorials(n - 2)) * n + previous)
    return cache[n]
```

so that `sum_factorials(4)` returns:

```
33
```

Comment: very nice answer!

Comment: Agree @blhsing ... deleted my answer. My goal was to let OP know the approach of two recursive functions ... and let OP think about "tuning".

Comment: @blhsing-- As mentioned in my solution, inefficiency is easily removed by the use of memoization which just adds a decorator to each function (i.e. https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php).

Answer (score 0):

Added memoization which would be used in practice for these types of recursive functions to improve efficiency by removing repetitive computations (i.e. https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php)

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:            
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper

@memoize
def sum_of_factorial(n):
  if n==0:
    return 0
  return factorial(n) + sum_of_factorial(n-1)

@memoize
def factorial(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1 
  else: 
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative single recursive solution with generators, using `functools.reduce` for multiplication:

```
from functools import reduce as _r
def fact_sum(n, f = True):
   if not f and n:
      yield from [n, *fact_sum(n - 1, f = False)]
   if f and n:
      new_n = _r(lambda x, y:x*y, list(fact_sum(n, f = False)))
      yield from [new_n, *fact_sum(n - 1, f = True)]

print(sum(fact_sum(3)))
print(sum(fact_sum(4)))
```

Output:

```
9
33
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is almost good, I have corrected it. Please check it below.

> You can try it online at https://rextester.com/AGS44863

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else: 
        mul_sum = 1
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            mul_sum *= i
        return factorial(n-1) + mul_sum

print(factorial(4)) # 33
```

To make sure, the above one is correct, you can also have a look at the below function which forms the expression (string) using recursion.

```
def factorial_expression(n):
    if str(n) == '0':
        return ""
    else: 
        if n == 1:
            return "1"
        mul_sum = "("
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            mul_sum += str(i) + "*"

        return (factorial_expression(n-1) + "+" + mul_sum.rstrip("*") + ")").lstrip("+")

# 1+(1*2)+(1*2*3)+(1*2*3*4)
print(factorial_expression(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why we need any subtraction or caches. Recursion can go forwards as well as backwards:

```
def f(n, i=1, factorial=1, result=1):
  if i == n:
    return result
  next = factorial * (i + 1)
  return f(n, i + 1, next, result + next)

print(f(4)) # 33
```

(This also seems slightly [faster](https://ideone.com/jp07ah) than blhsing's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58071468/2034787).)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if the math is right, probably is not, yet you might want to define a method and iterate through, that I'm guessing:

```
def factorial(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1 
  else: 
    return n * factorial(n-1)


def sum_of_factorial(n):
    sum_output = 0  
    while n >= 0:
        sum_output += factorial(n)
        n -= 1

    return sum_output

print(factorial(10))
print(sum_of_factorial(10))
```

Comment: This is not performing the sum using recursion.